# Salesforce objects property

Tags: sobject

I am running a business in which I provide different services to clients. Now, which object is used for services in salesforce.  suppose client want service from my company. Now the service I provide to the client. where to create a record for the service. I know about lead, account, contact. but I don't know which object is suitable for service or any other recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but if we are talking about a company who wants to provide service and support using Salesforce, that company should use Service Cloud (See this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/servicecloud-quick-look/servicecloud-quick-look-1?trail_id=service_cloud_move).

That company should use the Case object to save any kind of service/support request from the client (this can be inserted in Salesforce manually, throw email, web, chat or phone) and use different things like Auto-response Rule, Escalation Rule, Queue, Routing, etc. to be sure that the case is resolved as fast as possible by the right people and to let the clients know that they are important.

Comment: yes you understand correctly

Comment: so I use a Case object?

Comment: Yes, the Case object is the most important part of Service Cloud. For a correct implementation you need to decide how your clients are going to reach you with their problems (by email, phone, etc.) and how are you going to take care of that case and for that you need settings and other objects as well (Like Contact object to save the clients in salesforce)

Comment: You can find a lot of information about how to implement a correct flow using salesforce Service Cloud (SC) on the internet. You don't need everything, just choose whatever implementation is the best for the bussines

Comment: okay, I am on it, thanks for the advice